# Web Browser Forgetting Between Users

Tags: web-browser, cookies, session-management, browser-extensions, sensitive-data-exposure

I am planning to go door-to-door and host events in which people use a computer to login to the Arizona Secretary of State website, enter sensitive information (like address, social security number, driver's license number), to register to vote or to sign candidate petitions.

I wanted to know which browser I should use, if there were any browser settings, or if there were any extensions that would: disable autofill, forget cookies when they log out, and completely erase any other data between users?

Comment: I think a lot of people are going to be reluctant to enter their social security number on someone else's device (who knows where the device could be storing/sending this information?).  Having said that, running the browser in 'private mode' will delete all cookies, history, cached resources, etc. when the browser is restarted.

Comment: Eliter, I don't mean any offence, but anybody who enters sensitive data on your device is taking a huge risk. Even if you use private mode, how would they know for sure that you don't have a key-logger installed? How do they know it's not a completely fake website? They just have to hope that you're honest. I personally think you're honest, but the next person who goes door-to-door might not be.

Comment: @mti2935 You would be surprised how much people are willing to give their info. Arizona at Work has public computers where people input socials all the time without private browsing. There are also lots of companies that ask for your social over-the-phone to verify your identity (and most people don't worry about it). There was even a millionaire-thief that "surveyed" people and asked people for their socials (Matthew Cox) on the street, and they gave it to him and he used their identities later to make money. Anyway, there's an option to just ask for the driver's number.

Comment: @FireQuacker That last comment was for you as well. Do either of you have any ideas on what I can use, so that I don't have to open/close a new private window every time?

Comment: @Eliter You can write an extension or similar to do it for you. It's probably not worth the effort since closing the window takes 1 click and opening a new one can be done in 1 or 2 clicks. At best you'd be saving 1 or 2 clicks, at worst you'd have something that leaks information. Just close the window and open a new one (with a [shortcut for example](https://superuser.com/questions/153245/how-can-i-open-google-chrome-via-command-line-with-a-url-in-incognito-mode)).